# how to properly transform date to string and back in symfony form so can use date picker

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In my Symfony 4 app, I have an entity that includes a Date type field.  By default, Symfony presents this as a set of select boxes for month, day, year.  I've changed that to a text widget so that I can use a jQuery UI date picker.

But I'm running into problems trying to submit the form.

Here's the field on my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $start_date;
```

Here's how I'm displaying the field:

```
$builder->add('start_date', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',

                // prevents rendering it as type="date", to avoid HTML5 date pickers
                'html5' => false,

                // adds a class that can be selected in JavaScript
                'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            ])
```

With jquery and jqueryui on my page, this is allowing a datepicker to display.

Here's how I'm currently experimenting with converting from date to string and vice-versa.  At the moment, I'm just trying to use a hard-coded date, which of course I'll change once I have a clue what I'm doing.

```
$builder->get('start_date')
->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function ( $dateAsString ) {
        return new \DateTime('2019-01-01');
    },
    function ( $dateAsDate ) {
        return '2019-01-01';
    }
));
```

Submitting the form produces this error:
Expected argument of type "DateTimeInterface", "string" given.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can store the date in my entity as a date type while presenting it as a string in my form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I invite you to check out the [documentation of `DateType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html). You will find out that you can store your date in variety of formats depending on `input` option :

- string (e.g. 2011-06-05)
- datetime (a DateTime object)
- datetime_immutable (a DateTimeImmutable object)
- array (e.g. ['year' => 2011, 'month' => 06, 'day' => 05])
- timestamp (e.g. 1307232000)

This is an underlying **`model value`** in your entity. In your example you must chose `datetime` which is the default.

You made a right choise for `widget` option - `single_text`. Don't forget to set a right `format`. This is `view value`.

In your case you don't need to write your own data transformer. Symfony will take care of transforming your `model value` in `view value` and vice versa. It makes it using via `normalised value`:

```
`model data`(string, datetime, timestamp, etc.) -> `norm data` (`DateTime`) -> `view data` (string for widget=single_text, array for widget=choice)
```

and

```
`view data` (string for widget=single_text, array for widget=choice) -> `norm data` (`DateTime`) -> `model data`(string, datetime, timestamp, etc.)
```

While the formats of `view data` and `model data` vary, the format of `norm data` is always the same - `DateTime`. The model transformer you added returned `string` to be set to normalized data. That's why you got an error.

Comment: Thank you  for the detailed answer, VladRia!  This was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a predefined format to your formbuilder, like this

```
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                //default format of the date 
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',

                // prevents rendering it as type="date", to avoid HTML5 date pickers
                'html5' => false,

                // adds a class that can be selected in JavaScript
                'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            ])
```

You won't need the transformer in this case, the formbuilder will handle it.

Comment: Thanks, Marlies.  Very helpful info.  This worked!  I was torn which answer to accept, and chose Vlad's because I will need to change the date format to mm/dd/yy and his answer will allow other formats.  But your answer works perfectly as the quick solution.