# How to get DateTime object instead of string in POST_SUBMIT event of DateType form type?

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to create a custom Symfony Form Field Type based on DateType which performs some logic on the data when the form is submitted.

```
class CustomDateType extends AbstractType {
        ...

        public function getParent(): string {
            return DateType::class;
        }

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();                
            $this->logger->info('PRE: '.gettype($data));
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();                
            $this->logger->info('POST: '.gettype($data));
        });
    }
}

// Output:
PRE: string
POST: string
```

Both in `PRE_SUBMIT` and `POST_SUBMIT` the data is a simple string and not a `DateTime` instance.

Is there any way to get the resulting, validated `DateTime` object instead?

**EDIT 1:**

Of course I could convert the string to `DateTime` myself. However, the underlying `DateType` class can be configured to accept only specific formats, date ranges, etc. While re-creating all these conversions, checks, etc. myself is possible of course, it would be quite cumbersome. It would mean to re-invent the wheel. Isn't there an event / possibility to get the final DateTime object after the underlying DateType did its job to create it?

**EDIT 2:**

Another problem when trying to manually create a `DateTime` object from the given data string is, that the format is unknown.

While the format of the `DateType` field can be queried from its options, it uses the [ICU date format string](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax) PHP uses [different format strings](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php).

So, if the date field uses `dd.MM.yyyy` for example, this would be an invalid format to be used with `DateTime::createFromFormat('dd.MM.yyyy', $data)`.

Comment: You could use a dataTransformer (looks like this is what the [DateType class does](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php)) or you could just convert the string to a datetime object with normal vanila PHP (`$object = datetime::createfromformat(...)`)?

Comment: @Bossman Thanks, this would be possible of course. However this would require to re-implement the conversions, checks, etc. the underlying DateType already performs (see my edits of the question).

Comment: I know what you mean, however it has already gone through the original validation and conversion (via DateType::class) to a string so should be safe converting back to a DateTime object without anymore checks, right?

Comment: I tried to go this way and create the DateTime object myself. However, one does not know which format has to be used. The format string used by the DateType field is different from the expected format in `DateTime::createFromFormat(...)` (see my 2nd edit). Is is possible to convert the format?

Comment: You can use DateType and  add a custom ViewTransformer (with forcePrepend = true). In the transformer, you can change the string to a suitable format for DateType. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: @Artem In this case I would have to add the ViewTransformer to every `DateType` explicitly? This is what should be avoided by creating and using a custom sub type instead.

Comment: @AndreiHerford, thinking about this i think the way forward would be a dataTransformer (as i originally proposed and what *Artem* says). Maybe [this can be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775605/how-to-properly-transform-date-to-string-and-back-in-symfony-form-so-can-use-dat) also.

Comment: How about the `SUBMIT` event? That seems to return a DateTime object.

Comment: Or try [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get a timestamp then create the DateTime object...

Comment: Using FormExtension, you can add your custom ViewTransformer once for all DateTime fields. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: Also, you can create `CustomDateType` which extends DateType. In the `buildForm` method call `parent::buildForm` and  `$builder->addViewTransformer(new CustomDateTimeTransformer(), true)`